# Appending a Dictionary with row number and column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code that allows me to find all blanks in certain columns of a dataframe. Here is what I have:

```
req_cols = ['First Name*','Last Name*','Country*','Company*','Email Address*']
bad_nan=df[df[req_cols].isna().any(1)]
```

I am trying to add the missing cells or NAN values to an existing dictionary called "errors"

```
if not bad_nan.empty:
    errors.append({
        "row": [0],
        "column": [1],
        "message": "This is a required field"
})
```

this is what the dictionary looks like:

`{'row': [0], 'column': [1], 'message': 'This is a required field'}`

but I would like it to look like

`{'row': 2, 'column': First Name*, 'message': 'This is a required field'}`

I would like this to display all the cells that have a NaN value not just one

Comment: You want a dictionary of ALL `na` values, right? Not just one, correct?)

Comment: correct I want the dictionary to list all the na values for the variables in the req_cols

Comment: The best bet would be to fill all NA values with a string that is not in the other column such as NAN or NaN and then reference that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would loop through every cell in the dataframe `bad_nan` to append the row index and column name to the `errors` list. Please check if np.nan is still the same in the filtered `bad_nan`

```
errors = []
req_cols = ['First Name*','Last Name*','Country*','Company*','Email Address*']
#req_cols = df.columns

bad_nan = df.loc[df[req_cols].isna().any(1)]
for col in bad_nan.columns:
    bad_nan[col] = bad_nan[col].astype('str')
    for i in range(bad_nan.shape[0]):
        #print(bad_nan.loc[i, col])
        if bad_nan.loc[i, col] == 'nan':    #use print statement to check if string is 'nan'
            errors.append({ "row": i,
                            "column": col,
                            "message": "This is a required field" })
print(errors)
```

Comment: i get a keyerror when i run this. It raise 'if bad_nan.loc[i, col] == np.nan:' not sure what you mean by check if np.nan is that same in the filtered

Comment: I'm not sure why the np.nan values became string 'nan', so I've updated the code the check them in string type, see if it works

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you forgot something in your if statement.

```
if not bad_nan.empty:
    errors.append({
        "row": bad_nan[0],
        "column": bad_nan[1],
        "message": "This is a required field"
})
```

Could that be the problem?

Comment: I got a "ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). "

Comment: Then, try again with the original conditional statement.

Comment: got a keyerror; 0.  I have tried to use a for loop to do this but it gave me letter as my row instead of numbers and the columns werent columns in my df